# exception when sending email from Apex when setWhatId is set with recordId

Tags: apex, exception

i'm getting an exception when sending email from apex controller  class. I'm associating this email with recordId to show it under activity for that record.

here is the exception

> System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id: []

Here is the code .. for this post i changed the email address to 123@123.com . This very same code works when executed from anonymous window i.e. email is sent out and associated with record.

```
id idd = 'a8R0n0000008cepEAA';
String[] ccAddresses = new String[] {'123@123.com'}; 

Messaging.SingleEmailMessage OrderContactMail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        OrderContactMail.setCcAddresses(ccAddresses); 
        //OrderContactMail.SaveAsActivity(true);
        String messageBody = 'some sample message';
               OrderContactMail.setSubject('subject');
               OrderContactMail.setHtmlBody(messageBody);
               OrderContactMail.setSaveAsActivity(true);
               //OrderContactMail.setTargetObjectId(o.Contact__c);
               OrderContactMail.setWhatId(idd);
               //mails.add(OrderContactMail);


Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {OrderContactMail});
```

Comment: When the method invoked, is it invoked by you? Where are you using the method?

Comment: Check if running user has access to the record `a8R0n0000008cepEAA`, if same code works with anonymous window, could mean that your apex class runs in a `with sharing` mode

Comment: yes my class is using with sharing. here it is public with sharing class FileComponentController . Anonymous window also run in user mode with sharing, right?